# List<data> table=null; in java

Tags: java, generics, collections

I see this coding in Java file.

```
List <data> tables=null;
```

I can't understand the working of this.
Can you please explain me about this.

Comment: This is a declaration of variable `tables` of type `List<data>`. The variable is initialized to `null`. Usually you see `= new ArrayList<data>()` or something like that in place of `null`.

Comment: IT means you have a list which is supposed to contain items of type `tables` and name of the list is tables. Initially you are pointing it to `null`.

Comment: Sometimes you need to initiate the variable before you can use it.

Comment: This is a declaration of  `tables` variable. It is  a `List` of `data`. and it has initialized to `null`

Comment: Take a look at java **generics classes** ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code declares a variable `tables` of type `List<Data>`, and initialize it to `null`. (I change your `data` to `Data` to match the java convention)

I think you're in trouble with the `<Data>` part.

So let me say:
`List` is a **generic** class, which can be parametrized with another type. You can write `List<String>` or `List<Number>` for example, and `List::get(int index)` returns an object of the parametrized type.

More information in the [Oracle's tutorial about generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Answer (score 0):

It creates a reference called `tables` which can refer to an object that implements the `List` Interface (i.e. `ArrayList<data>`, `LinkedList<data>`), currently it refers to `null`. The `List` may hold values of type `data`.